# using bash commands in python on mac: error 127

Tags: python, bash, macos

I am using am using Python 2.7 on MacOS and want to use a bash command within a python script.

```
command = "someProgram --option1 value 1 --option2 value 2"
```

I had to include the path of this program in my bash_profile in order to run it. I tested so far:

```
os.system(command)
```

and

```
subprocess.check_call(command.split(" "),shell=True)
```

Neither worked. The latter threw error 127 and the first one only returned 32512. A google search told me that this occurs when the command is not known.

If I now start this command within the terminal everything works perfectly fine.

Do I have to include something such that python can find this command? Why is this behavior?

Comment: What is the command?

Comment: What is the command?

Comment: If `someProgram` isn't in your PATH, well, there you are. And `command.split(" ")` won't work for reasons that should be completely obvious when your values can have spaces in them.

Comment: If you used `command = ['someProgram', '--option1', 'value 1', '--option2', 'value 2']` with `subprocess.check_call(command)` (no `shell=True`), you'd be eliminating a whole class of parsing issues. Make it `/fully/qualified/path/to/someProgram` to eliminate possible PATH problems.

Comment: BTW, when you say "bash command", do you **really** mean "bash command"? Because if you're giving it a command that works with `/bin/bash` but not `/bin/sh`, then there's an obvious explanation. Likewise if it's a shell function or alias defined in your `~/.bashrc` or the like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help. The final solution is kind of stupid. I started spyder via the anaconda GUI. If I do so the above code does not work.

If I run this directly via the console or start spyder via the console everything is fine. It seems that the bash_profile is not loaded when spyder is loaded but requires the console to do so

Answer (score 1):

With `shell=True` the cmd needs to be a string.

`subprocess.check_call(command, shell=True)`

where command is of type `str`

Comment: From that discussion: 'If args is a sequence, the first item specifies the command string, and any additional items will be treated as additional arguments to the shell itself.' With a list, arguments to the program would instead be passed as arguments to the shell.

Comment: Probably a quoting issue with the option values. Try with command = """someProgram --option1='value 1' --option2='value 2' """

Comment: Why go through all that trouble instead of passing a proper argv array instead to avoid having a shell (and all the potential bugs that go with them -- injection attacks on your security, shellshock-style environment attacks, quoting bugs, etc) at all?

Comment: Would agree, though sometimes you really do need a shell because the program expects to be run in a shell and breaks without it. In general I agree, though there are cases where that is not appropriate.